# CursorAdapter bindView disorder

Tags: android, listview, android-cursoradapter

i'm trying to populate a ListView from a SQliteDatabase with Cursor and Loader, but all items are displayed in total disorder

My CursorAdapter class

```
@Override
public void bindView(View view, Context context, Cursor c) {
    ItemHolder holder = null;
    try{
        holder = (ItemHolder) view.getTag();
    } catch (Exception e){
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    if(holder != null){
        System.out.println("b "+holder.position);
    }

}

@Override
public View newView(Context context, Cursor c, ViewGroup parent) {
    LayoutInflater inflater = (LayoutInflater)context.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
    View nView = inflater.inflate(layoutID, parent, false);

    ItemHolder holder = new ItemHolder();
    System.out.println("a "+c.getPosition());
    holder.position = c.getPosition();
    nView.setTag(holder);

    return nView;
}
```

Logcat output after a single full scroll return (a is position in newView() and b in bindView() )

```
a 0
b 0
a 1
b 1
a 2
b 2
b 0
```

instead of

```
a 0
b 0
a 1
b 1
a 2
b 2
a 3
b 3
```

A check of the cursor in the adapter return correct data

```
c.moveToFirst();
    for(int i = 0; i < c.getCount(); i++){
        System.out.println(i+" "+c.getString(c.getColumnIndex(COL_NAME)));
        c.moveToNext();
    }
```

I use the latest anroid.support.v4 library

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add an `ORDER BY` clause to your SQL statement, that sorts the result of your query. Check out [the documentation](http://www.sqlite.org/lang_select.html) or [this example](http://zetcode.com/db/sqlite/select/) for more details.

Sample:

```
SELECT * FROM <table> ORDER BY <column>;
```

**p.s.**: if you are using `database.query(...)` you can add parameter for the sort column here (see `orderBy`):

```
query(String table, String[] columns, String selection, 
      String[] selectionArgs, String groupBy, String having, String orderBy)
```

Check out the [Android documentation](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/database/sqlite/SQLiteDatabase.html).